# Grails PagedResultList

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is there any way to get a PagedResultList in grails without using criteria?  I would like to avoid criteria as they are slightly more complex and make unit testing rather annoying.  Code Below

```
def pagedResultList = MyDomainClass.createCriteria().list(max:10, offset:0) 
                                                    { order("id", "asc") }

//Below does not return pagedResultList
def aList = MyDomainClass.list(sort:"id", order:"asc", max:10, offset: 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PagedResultList` is just used to wrap the results of Criteria-based queries (you can see its use [in the source here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/7a455ace8b90d6f04d0247514ca086145ca2fce5/grails-hibernate/src/main/groovy/grails/orm/HibernateCriteriaBuilder.java#L1110)). If you really want to use it, you could always just [invoke the constructor directly](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/api/grails/orm/PagedResultList.html#PagedResultList%28java.util.List%29), since it will handle any list. Of course the `totalCount` property (which is probably what you are interested in) will then be unset.

If the idea is to get both the paged results list and the total number of results, I'm not aware of any magic that can get both in one query (even the use of `PagedResultList` in the source linked above issues two queries).

Comment: Ahh, I didn't realize it was running two queries to begin with.  Now that I think about it I guess it makes sense that it is doing this.  The only way it would have been able not to is to would be to list then to sort and order on the app side, instead of the sql side.

Answer (score 4):

This seems to break in Grails 2.x because there is no costructor that just takes a list.  Compare http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/api/grails/orm/PagedResultList.html and http://docs.huihoo.com/grails/1.3.7/api/grails/orm/PagedResultList.html

Comment: I can't see a difference in the implemented (public) methods either, which is interesting.  Depending on what you are wanting to do you could create your own implementation based on java.util.List which adds a totalCount getter/setter.

Comment: yes I did this, and I probably should have mentioned that ;-)